# Laravel schedule:run command is not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, bitnami

I am setting background schedule in laravel on live server (Linux). I am using bitnami.  But `schedule:run` is not working when i am using comand like this:

```
* * * * * /opt/bitnami/php/bin/php /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/turnfitter/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I also tried like this:

```
* * * * * php artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1 ###
```

No error occurs but schedule is not working.

When i am trying like that:

```
php artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

or like

```
/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/turnfitter/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

without asterisk (*) then it works but only one command processed which I set to every minute in my schedule in kernel like this:

```
$schedule->command('payment:check')->everyMinute();
```

But it only run once when I run `schedule:run` command after that do nothing. Other commands I am calling hourly, daily etc. are not working at all.

Please can any one tell what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Bitnami LAMP Stack available at https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp

These are the steps I followed to successfully set the Schedule on Laravel:

- Uncomment the line below on the Apache congirutation file `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf`:

  ```
  #Include "/opt/bitnami/lampstack-5.6.26-3/frameworks/laravel/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
  ```
- Edit the method schedule on the file `/opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/app/Console/Kernel.php`:

  ```
  protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
  {
      $schedule->exec('echo "Hello World"')
        ->everyMinute()
        ->appendOutputTo('/tmp/laravel.log');
  }
  ```
- Restart Apache: `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache`
- Run: `/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php /opt/bitnami/frameworks/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Results:

- The Laravel Sample project was available at: http://127.0.0.1/laravel/
- Every minute a "Hello world!" line was added on /tmp/laravel.log

You should visit:

- Bitnami Laravel Documentation:
  https://docs.bitnami.com/general/components/php-frameworks/#laravel
- Laravel Official Documentation (Scheduling): https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling

Comment: Sorry, I'm not so clear as I have also problem with it with my laravel (use vhost outside bitnami lampstack), do I need to follow your answer by `uncomment apache config file`?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel's `php artisan schedule:run` command runs schedulers only once. In order to make it work you need to add this command to cron configuration file (crontab) which is located at /etc directory. Follow the following steps:

Step 1:
Add cron entry to crontab file [Open file using nano `/etc/crontab`]

```
* * * * * root php path/to/artisan schedule:run
```

Note: 
-Meaning of **** is to run the command every minute
-root is username, you should specify appropriate username
-Please do specify full path to artisan command in your laravel project.

Step 2:
Restart the service

```
> sudo service cron reload   
> sudo service cron stop  
> sudo service cron start
```

To check status of cron, run `sudo service cron status`

Step 3: 
Make sure that you have written code in schedule function in App/Console/Kernel. Here is what I wrote there:

```
   protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function(){
            Mail::send([],[],
                function ($m){
                    $m->to(['test@example.com'],'Notify')
                        ->subject('Renewal Notification')
                        ->setBody('You have upcoming renewal.');
                });
        })->everyTenMinutes();
    }
```

Laravel provides lots of function to schedule your calls or commands. I have used `everyTenMinutes()` function. Howeve, Laravel internally works on these schedules, we should only make sure that we are calling `schedule:run` command frequently using single entry (mentioned in step 1) in cron config file.